# What does --) mean in bash's case struture?

Tags: bash, shell, case

I have seen a code snippet containing a case structure.

```
while true;
do
    case "$1" in
        --prepare)
            echo "prepare"
            ENV_PREPARE
            exit 0
            ;;
        --sleep)
            SLEEP_TIME=$2
            shift 2
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Internal error!"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

What does  --) mean hrer in bash's case struture?

```
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
```

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It is just `--` two dashes characters in this particular case. Someone obviously wrote this code to parse script's arguments and went with own solutions using `case`. Im pretty sure, that if you explore code below, you will find there `$2` and may be `$3` and so on. `--` simply used as - "Stop processing options(no more options), all other parameters are data". Where is  data could be for example source /destination, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn’t mean anything special to bash.

The author of that snippet wanted to match two hyphens by themselves without any other characters. Literally "--".

Many Unix command-line tools, especially from the GNU heritage, let you use "--" as a delimiter to mean “nothing past this point should be treated as an option; the rest of this command line is made up of arguments (such as a list of filenames for a command that acts on files)”. That way you can, say, delete a file named "--help", by entering:

```
 rm -- --help
```

It keeps `rm` from thinking that "--help" is a long option to see the help statement. (This is a poor example but I think you get what I mean.)

I think the author of that script wanted to make "--" work like that in his script.